# Gene not found in Affymetrix expression profiles

Tags: microarray, gene-expression, identifiers

I am studying the ABA network in A. thaliana, consisting of HB7, ABI1 and AREB2. The AGI code I was given are, respectively: AT2G46680, AT4G26080 and AT1G45249.

I downloaded the following [file](https://www.arabidopsis.org/download_files/Microarrays/Affymetrix/affy_ATH1_array_elements-2010-12-20.txt) in order to convert the array element name to the AGI one, but I am not able to find AT1G45249 in the above file. How can I check whether [AT1G45249](https://www.arabidopsis.org/servlets/TairObject?type=locus&name=AT1G45249) has another name? Or even better, how can I check what is the array element name in Affymetrix (GPL198) corresponding to AT1G45249. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use  `org.At.tair.db`: Genome wide annotation for Arabidopsis, which is an R package available on [Bioconductor](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/data/annotation/html/org.At.tair.db.html) to extract gene symbols.